# value of variable is not equal to value in this code

Tags: python, parsing, variables, operators, analysis

in the following code, i have a variable "split_data[i]", i am comparing each element of this variable to a file in "text variable:

```
    i = 0
    while i < len(split_data):
        print(split_data[i])
        if  split_data[i] in text: #string in present in the text file
            print("Matched" )
        else:
            print("not matched" )    
        i += 1
```

the value of **split_data[4]** is **'03:31'** which is present in the **text** but still the output is "not matched"
whereas if my code is like this:

```
    i = 0
    while i < len(split_data):
        print(split_data[i])
        if  '03:31' in text: #string in present in the text file
            print("Matched" )
        else:
            print("not matched" )    
        i += 1
```

the output is matched.
or else we can say:

```
    if '03:31' in split_data[4]:
        print("true")
    else:
        print('false')
```

is true but

```
    if '03:31' == split_data[4]:
        print("true")
    else:
        print('false')
```

is false

this is my whole code :

```
import mysql.connector
import numpy as np
conn=mysql.connector.connect(user="root", password="",
                             host="localhost", database="videojs")

# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method

def read_from_db():

    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select time_arr from info where id ='53'")
    data=cursor.fetchone()
    print(data)

    the_new_list = [x.split(',') for x in data]
    print(the_new_list)
    str_data = ''.join(map(str, the_new_list))
    print(len(str_data))
    split_data=str_data.strip('[]').split(',')
    print(split_data)
    print(len(split_data))  

    i = 0
    while i
```

please guide me how to resolve this i am a beginner

this is the data in text:

```
    1
    00:00 --> 00:06
    welcome to your very<font color="#CCCCCC"> first tutorial</font><font 
    color="#E5E5E5"> on</font>

    2
    00:02 --> 00:08
    beginning HTML HTML<font color="#E5E5E5"> is the bedrock</font><font 
    color="#CCCCCC"> of</font>

    3
    00:06 --> 00:10
    <font color="#CCCCCC">the world wide web</font><font color="#E5E5E5"> 
     and if you're going</font>

     4  
     00:08 --> 03:31
    <font color="#CCCCCC">to do anything</font><font color="#E5E5E5"> 
    even</font><font color="#CCCCCC"> in</font><font color="#E5E5E5"> other 
    languages</font>
```

Comment: most likely, 'split_data[4]' does not contain what you think it does. Since you're printing it beforehand and can thus see the value, the most likely explanation would be that it contains some sort of whitespace.

Comment: can you please post the text?

Comment: yes i have updated the text, ohk zinki even if there might be can you please tell me how to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you may want to revisit your looping construct. 
Consider the Snippet:

```
text        = "one two three four five"
split_data  = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]

for i in split_data:
    print( "matched" if i in text else "not matched" )
```

Comment: nooo, this does not work and i dont have any problem with loops.. please help me out